# помогите улучшить код язык си

Tags: c++, c, инспекция-кода

подскажите как можно написать этот код проще если такое возможно
код работает как надо он берет ввод и считает каждую букву в алфавите и выводит на экран даже если буквы такой нет и он должен читать только маленькие буквы а большие и другие символы и даже пробелы он считает за другие символы количество которых он выводит в конце

вот скрин[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
int main() {
    char ch[100];
    int numberOfTimesAppeared = 0;
    int numberOfOtherCharsAppeared = 0;
    
    printf("Please enter your character set:\n");
    gets(ch); 
    
    for (char letter = 'a'; letter != '{'; letter++) {
        numberOfTimesAppeared = 0;
        for (int i = 0; ch[i] != NULL; i++) {
            if (letter == ch[i]) {
                numberOfTimesAppeared++;
            }
            if (letter > 'a'){
                continue;
            }
            if (!islower(ch[i]))
            {
                numberOfOtherCharsAppeared++;
            }
        }
        printf(
            "letter %c appeared %d time in the given set of characters\n",
            letter, numberOfTimesAppeared
        );
    }
    printf(
        "number of other characters in the given set was: %d\n",
        numberOfOtherCharsAppeared
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно создать массив, где будут храниться количества упоминаний символов. Тогда получится обойтись без вложенных циклов, что повысит производительность.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char ch[100];
    int numberOfOtherCharsAppeared = 0;
    int chs['{'-'a'] = {0};

    printf("Please enter your character set:\n");
    gets(ch); 
    
    for (int i = 0; ch[i] != NULL; i++) {
        if (ch[i]>='a' && ch[i]<'{') {
            chs[ch[i]-'a']++;
        } else {
            numberOfOtherCharsAppeared++;
        }
    }
    
    for (int i = 0; i<sizeof(chs)/sizeof(int); i++) {
        printf(
            "letter %c appeared %d time in the given set of characters\n",
            (char)(i+'a'), chs[i]
        );
    }
    printf(
        "number of other characters in the given set was: %d\n",
        numberOfOtherCharsAppeared
    );
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ну... я бы делал так:

```
int main()
{
    char cnt[26] = {0}, count = 0;
    printf("Please enter your character set:\n");
    for(int c = fgetc(stdin); c != '\n' && c != EOF; c = fgetc(stdin))
    {
        ++count;
        if (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z') cnt [c-'a']++;
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < 26; ++i)
    {
        printf("letter %c appeared %d time in the given set of characters\n",
               'a'+i,cnt[i]);
        count -= cnt[i];
    }
    printf("number of other characters in the given set was: %d\n",count);
}
```